# Visa Type for a Kenyan Citizen wishing to settle permanently in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, family

I did apply for a job in the UK while in Kenya and the Company (to which I applied for) wrote and guaranteed me that I'll can be given the job as long as I'm present in the United Kingdom .
I'm preparing for my travel documents. I have a family member, UNCLE, who live in the United Kingdom as a EU National and has agreed to accommodate me for the couple of weeks I'll be in the UK before I get my first salary so I may start depending on myself and even settle in the United Kingdom. 
What type of Visa I'm I supposed to apply For?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I think your case as it is not strong enough. Applications on this premise will get rejected fast unless there is an exceptionally strong plea. Try corresponding with the employer to issue a better document and give you a job offer letter and to help in immigration. Just stating that you can have the job if you are here is no commitment

Comment: Maybe this is lost in translation, but the way the company said that, they are saying they will employ you if you are physically in the UK, implying they don't care if you're legal to work in the UK, implying "sneak in on a lorry, or lie and come in on a tourist visa".   **Don't do that.  It won't work** and you will get caught and this will make it near impossible to enter the UK properly in the future.

Comment: Hanky Panky & Harper, My main concern ain't about the Job. My main concern is I want to go and settle in the UK and my Uncle is willing to accommodate me. What type of Visa I'm I supposed to apply?

Comment: Percival, you should [edit] and add your comment in the question to clarify it instead.

Comment: There is no visa to simply settle in the UK. There are visas to enter the UK for various purposes, such as short term visits, studying, and investing lots of money. The closest to your situation is Tier 2, but you would need an employer who is much more pro-active about sponsoring you.

Answer (score 3):

**What type of Visa I'm I supposed to apply For?**

Based on what you wrote you would apply for a Tier 2 visa. This is a visa that allows you to come to the UK and hold a job.

You would apply for a T2 visa using the online form but before starting you should have your 'certificate of sponsorship'. I got the impression that you did not have one yet, so take careful note that you will not get a visa unless you have one.  You get one from your sponsor, i.e., your prospective employer.

Also, a UK company cannot offer to employ you unless they conduct a Resident Market Labour Test and I got the impression that this has not been done.

Those two impressions add up to the possibility that you might be vulnerable to getting scammed. The way to tell is if the company needs you to send them a fee for something. In a proper T2 offer there is never a reason for the applicant to send the employer a fee.

**About your uncle.,.**

It's great to have a relative who can provide you with lodging while you get your bearings and start out living on your own.  But the UK doesn't allow people just to show up and start living as a resident. **As a Kenyan, you will need an entry clearance before you can board a flight to the UK**, and the entry clearance will have an end date by which you need to be out of the UK (or become an overstayer).

The entry clearance can be the T2 visa I mentioned above, or a visitor visa. An uncle is not a close enough relative to benefit you as a family visitor.

Kenyan applications are accepted at the High Commission in Nairobi and sent to the decision-making centre in Pretoria.  As consulates go, Pretoria can be quite awkward for Kenyans so I would advise you to be diligent and do the very best job you can on your application.

[image]